# Suppressing marmap messages in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Say I have the following RMarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Mr. Test"
date: "October 15, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, error = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
# Load library
library(marmap)

# Download bathymetry data and keep for future use
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -5, lon2 = 5, lat1 = -5, lat2 = 5, resolution = 1, keep = TRUE)

# Perform same command again, which reads downloaded file
invisible(bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -5, lon2 = 5, lat1 = -5, lat2 = 5, resolution = 1, keep = TRUE))
```
````

This uses the `marmap` package to download and load some data into R. Then, it loads the data again from the local file. This gives the following output:

[image]

Notice that I try suppressing all output from this chunk using chunk options, whether an error, message, or warning, yet there is still output. I even tried wrapping the commands in `invisible` and still I get output. Looking at the raw code for `getNOAA.bathy`, I see that the author is using `cat` to print output rather than `message`. In this case, how do I silence the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have a solution. Apparently, `invisible` alone won't do the job, but `invisible(capture.output())` will. Any clarification as to why this is the case would be appreciated.

Comment: aye. b/c the author did something in really bad form and used `cat()` instead of `message()`: https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/blob/4b5a9845cd6c2a77009c1a369000ea23cdc288de/R/getNOAA.bathy.R#L39  ; the only way to "suppress" `cat()` output is via what you did

Comment: Bad, bad developper! I replaced `cat()` by `message()` in `getNOA.bathy()`and pushed the changes to github. Other instances of cat() may remain in some functions but I don't have time to fix all of them right now. I'll do this ASAP and submit an updated version of the package to the CRAN servers in a few days.

Comment: @Benoit Thanks for fixing this so quickly!